# Error with "BatchedBridge" while running expo start command

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm trying to run my React-native app with the command **expo start** from my terminal and when I'm trying to access my app from my Android phone, here's the error I get :

`Could not get BatchedBridge make sure your bundle is packaged correctly`

It seems the error appears from time to time (I saw some topics over there) but none of the solutions worked for me.

Here the versions of expo and react :

```
"expo": "~46.0.7",
"react": "^18.0.0",
"react-native": "^0.69.6",
```

A lot of answers concerned the upgrade of react-native package but I can't do that because of my expo version.

Does someone ever faced a similar problem using expo and react-native ?

Thanks :)

From my MacOS terminal, I tried :

```
expo start
```

Then, from my Android mobile, I scanned the QR code which launched the app.

The splash screen appeared for a second and the error message appeared.